# systemd-logind is working at full speed and my computer is buzzing when I close the laptop lid

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm using Arch Linux, which has a rolling update system. For some time (probably since the last update, but I'm not sure), when I close my laptop lid, the fan starts to make a lot of noise. I checked what program loads the processor so. I executed such a command:

```
sleep 12 && echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix > htop.html
```

I closed my laptop, which started buzzing after about 10 seconds, and after 12 seconds I opened it. Here is a screenshot from the htop command made with the above command:

[image]

As you can see, buzzing is caused by systemd-logind program. My laptop is buzzing only with the closed lid. When the laptop lid is open, I don't hear the buzzing (even after screen is locked with WINDOWS + L). If that's important, I use the GNOME desktop environment.

How to fix it and why this program makes such noise?

Comment: Your system is not suspending (sleeping) properly, and is getting warm (display may be on) causing the fan to run. Update the Power Driver for the machine, restart, and test suspend manually with the lid open to see if it suspends properly.

Comment: ACPI? The latest package is from 2017.

Comment: The power driver is different from the ACPI driver. See if you can find a newer power driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem.

I tried to suspend my computer with the `systemctl suspend` command and found that `suspend.target` is masked. Then I remembered that I did it myself when I wanted to play many hours of spotify music and the suspending computer bothered me...

To solve the problem I just unmasked it ...